# Implement Accordion to SecondScreen in Kivy ScreenManager

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am not able to place an AccordionItem on a screen of the Kivy ScreenManager. For this I have to define something like root = Accordion(). But I don't know where the ScreenLayout is defined. I build it up in pure python, cause i´m complete new to Kivy, but not new to python.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem



class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


        btn1 = Button(
            text='change screen',
            size_hint=(.5, .05),
            pos_hint={'left':0, 'top':1}
            )
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        self.add_widget(btn1)


    def changer(self,*args):

        self.manager.current = 'screen2'

    def test(self,instance):
        print('This is a test')


class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        btn2 = Button(
            text='change screen',
            size_hint=(.5, .25),
            pos_hint={'left':0, 'top':1}
            )
        btn2.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        self.add_widget(btn2)


        title = ["Title 1", "Title 2","Title 3","Title 4","Title 5"]


        for x in range(5):

            item = AccordionItem(title= title[x])
            item.add_widget(Label(text='Very big content\n' * 10))
            self.add_widget(item)

        return sm



    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'

    def test(self,instance):
        print('This is another test')


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):


        sm = ScreenManager()

        sc1 = ScreenOne(name='screen1')
        sc2 = ScreenTwo(name='screen2')        

        sm.add_widget(sc1)
        sm.add_widget(sc2)

        print (sm.screen_names)

        return sm




if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

ScreenTwo should show the 5 AccordionItems. But they overlap and are not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a [Screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) displays nothing: it’s just a [RelativeLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout). Therefore, in order to display a [Button](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html) and an [Accordion](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.accordion.html) widgets in the second screen, you need to enclose those two widgets in a [layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/layouts.html) e.g. [BoxLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html).

## Example

The following snippets illustrates using a `BoxLayout` widget to enclose a `Button` and an `Accordion` widgets.

### Snippets - py file

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

...

class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')    # instantiate BoxLayout
        self.add_widget(layout)    # add BoxLayout to screen

        btn2 = Button(
            text='change screen',
            size_hint=(.5, .05),
        )
        btn2.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        layout.add_widget(btn2)    # add Button to BoxLayout

        title = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5"]

        accordion = Accordion()    # instantiate Accordion
        layout.add_widget(accordion)    # add Accordion to BoxLayout

        for x in range(5):
            item = AccordionItem(title=title[x])
            item.add_widget(Label(text='Very big content\n' * 10))
            accordion.add_widget(item)    # add AccordionItem to Accordion
```

## Output

[image: Second Screen - Button & Accordion]